# Same width column with Material-UI 1 Grid

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

Is there any way to create one column of same-width items with Material-UI Grid system? I have the following code

```
<Grid container align="center" direction="column">
    <Grid item className={classes.item}>
        <img src={logo}/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item>
        <TextField label={messages.login.username} fullWidth />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item >
        <TextField label={messages.login.password} fullWidth />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item>
        <Button color="primary" raised>{messages.login.loginBtn}</Button>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Ideally I want all the `Grid items` to be of equal width, possibly the width of their `container`. I have tried setting `xs=12` on all `items` but nothing changes.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In the Grid container try to replace the `align="center"` with `align="stretch"`, so that all the Grid items will stretch and have the same width as their parent.

This demo in the [documentation](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/layout/grid/#interactive) is explanatory and fun to play with

Comment: Yeah I totally missed this demo as well as this flex option.